# How to add days (as values of a column) to date?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a problem with adding days (numbers) to date format columns in Spark. I know that there is a function `date_add` that takes two arguments - date column and integer:

```
date_add(date startdate, tinyint/smallint/int days)
```

I'd like to use a column value that is of type integer instead (not an integer itself).

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
val data = Seq(
    (0, "2016-01-1"),
    (1, "2016-02-2"),
    (2, "2016-03-22"),
    (3, "2016-04-25"),
    (4, "2016-05-21"),
    (5, "2016-06-1"),
    (6, "2016-03-21"))
).toDF("id", "date")
```

I can simply add integers to dates:

```
val date_add_fun = 
data.select(
    $"id",
    $"date",
    date_add($"date", 1)
)
```

But I cannot use a column expression that contains the values:

```
val date_add_fun = 
data.select(
    $"id",
    $"date",
    date_add($"date", $"id")
)
```

It gives error:

```
<console>:60: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName
 required: Int
           date_add($"date", $"id")
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to use column is date_add function? Or what is the workaround?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `expr`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr

data.withColumn("future", expr("date_add(date, id)")).show
// +---+----------+----------+
// | id|      date|    future|
// +---+----------+----------+
// |  0| 2016-01-1|2016-01-01|
// |  1| 2016-02-2|2016-02-03|
// |  2|2016-03-22|2016-03-24|
// |  3|2016-04-25|2016-04-28|
// |  4|2016-05-21|2016-05-25|
// |  5| 2016-06-1|2016-06-06|
// |  6|2016-03-21|2016-03-27|
// +---+----------+----------+
```

`selectExpr` could be use in a similar way:

```
data.selectExpr("*", "date_add(date, id) as future").show
```

Answer (score 4):

The other answers work but aren't a drop in replacement for the existing date_add function. 
 I had a case where `expr` wouldn't work for me, so here is a drop in replacement:

```
def date_add(date: Column, days: Column) = {
    new Column(DateAdd(date.expr, days.expr))
}
```

Basically, all the machinery is there in Spark to do this already, the function signature for `date_add` just forces it to be a literal.

Comment: Underrated answer. Also, really stupid that it forces the column to a literal. Sounds like it was not reviewed or something.

Comment: For the Python developers who are here, you can simply add a data column to another column together using +

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sql expression as

```
data.createOrReplaceTempView("table")
sqlContext.sql("select id, date, date_add(`date`, `id`) as added_date from table").show(false)
```

which would give you

```
+---+----------+----------+
|id |date      |added_date|
+---+----------+----------+
|0  |2016-01-1 |2016-01-01|
|1  |2016-02-2 |2016-02-03|
|2  |2016-03-22|2016-03-24|
|3  |2016-04-25|2016-04-28|
|4  |2016-05-21|2016-05-25|
|5  |2016-06-1 |2016-06-06|
|6  |2016-03-21|2016-03-27|
+---+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

For the Python developers who are here, you can simply add a date column to another column together using `+`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

new_df = df.withColumn("new_date", F.col("date") + F.col("offset"))
```

Juste make sure that the offset column is int/smallint/tinyint.