# Last Date Id Of Previous Months

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark-sql, days

My data-frame has a DateId (i.e. an integer column defining a date as a number of days since 1993-06-25). Objective is to calculate date id of the last day of month prior to each date in the column:

```
DateId ->  _intermittent calc Date_       -> _result LastDayOfPriorMonthId_
9063   ->  2018-04-18                     -> 9045 (i.e. 2018-03-31)
8771   ->  2017-06-30                     -> 8741 (i.e. 2017-05-31)
9175   ->  2018-08-08                     -> 9167 (i.e. 2018-07-31)
```

Solution would be really easy, but I'm running into issues with type conversion:

```
val a = Seq(9063, 8771, 9175).toDF("DateId")
val timeStart = to_date(lit("1993-06-25"))


val dateIdAdd : (Column) => Column = x => {x - date_add(timeStart, x).DATE_OF_MONTH}
```

The function compilation is failing with following error:

```
notebook:2: error: type mismatch;
found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
required: Int
   x - date_add(timeStart, x).DATE_OF_MONTH
```

Expressions like `.cast(IntegerType)` do not change the outcome (`x` is still a spark Column type and `.cast(Int)` is not applicable.

Please note: similar problem was addressed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800188/how-to-add-days-as-values-of-a-column-to-date) SO question, but the same approach is failing when the `timeStart` constant is applied here. Also using function would be preferred over expression, because the same calculation is used multiple columns with real data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you translate from Java? Sorry, I don’t code Scala (yet).

```
private static final LocalDate baseDate = LocalDate.of(1993, Month.JUNE, 25);

public static long dateIdAdd(long dateId) {
    LocalDate date = baseDate.plusDays(dateId);
    LocalDate lastOfPrevMonth = YearMonth.from(date).minusMonths(1).atEndOfMonth();
    return ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(baseDate, lastOfPrevMonth);
}
```

Edit: according to you (Dan, the asker), the Scala version is:

```
val baseDate = LocalDate.of(1993, Month.JUNE, 25)
val lastDayIdOfPriorMonth = udf((dateId : Long) => {
    val date = baseDate.plusDays(dateId)
    val lastOfPrevMonth = YearMonth.from(date).minusMonths(1).atEndOfMonth()
    ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(baseDate, lastOfPrevMonth)
})
```

Let’s try it with your example dates (Java again):

```
    System.out.println("9063 -> " + dateIdAdd(9063));
    System.out.println("8771 -> " + dateIdAdd(8771));
    System.out.println("9175 -> " + dateIdAdd(9175));
```

This prints:

```
9063 -> 9045
8771 -> 8741
9175 -> 9167
```

In your question you gave 9176 as desired result in the last case, but I believe that was a typo?

And please enjoy how clear and self-explanatory the code is.

Comment: You're right about typo in the original description. The 9167 is the right answer - my text string based hack generates the same result (editing the original question to avoid confusion).

Comment: your solution requires 3 additional libraries (`import java.time
import java.time._ 
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit`)

the Scala version is:
   `val baseDate = LocalDate.of(1993, Month.JUNE, 25)

    val lastDayIdOfPriorMonth = udf((dateId : Long) => {
      val date = baseDate.plusDays(dateId)
      val lastOfPrevMonth = YearMonth.from(date).minusMonths(1).atEndOfMonth()
      ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(baseDate, lastOfPrevMonth)
    })`



Please claim this solution in your answer!

Comment: Thanks for the Scala translation. I have added it to the answer. Is that the way you count libraries in Scala? In Java I would just have said it requires the JDK, that is, no additional libraries. It does require imports of `java.time._` and `java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit`.

Comment: Yes, per my limited knowledge, the libraries have to be imported. May be there is an alternative, but tutorials and examples are using imports regularly(e.g. https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/dataframes-datasets/introduction-to-dataframes-scala.html)

Comment: I think it’s more a question of word usage. *Classes*  have to be imported (where I work, 50 import statements is not that uncommon, and we don’t regard it as a problem in itself). There are usually many classes in a *library*.

Answer (score 0):

After testing many options with Scala conversion function, hack based on UDF with Java string and `SimpleDateFormat` the only thing I could figure out:

```
val dateIdAdd = udf((dateId : Long) => {
   val d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
   val ts = d.parse("1993-06-25")
   val tc = d.format(new Date(ts.getTime() + (24 * 3600 * 1000 * dateId)))
   dateId - Integer.parseInt(tc.substring(tc.length()-2))
})
```

After adding another support function for validation and a simple select:

```
val dateIdToDate = udf((dateId : Long) => {
  val d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
  val ts = d.parse("1993-06-25")
  d.format(new Date(ts.getTime() + (24 * 3600 * 1000 * dateId)))
})

val aa = a.select($"*"
             , dateIdToDate($"DateId") as "CalcDateFromId"
             , dateIdAdd($"DateId") as "CalcLastDayOfMonthId")

display(aa)
```

Expected results are generated (but I doubt this is the most efficient way available):

```
DateId  CalcDateFromId  CalcLastDayOfMonthId
9063    4/18/2018       9045
8771    6/30/2017       8741
9175    8/8/2018        9167
```